# Delphi (6 & XE8), MSMQ, EOleException, Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: delphi, msmq, delphi-xe8

My Windows service throws an EOleException exception when the code tries to access the 'Body' property of a MSMQ message.
The error is intermittent and the service can run for a month without an issue.
The message payload is an XML string.
The service processes a small number of messages a day (~10) and the message payload is small <900 bytes.
The messages are sent to the MSMQ Server by a BizTalk application and event sinked in the service.
I've ported the code from D6 to XE8 (I imported the mqoa30.tlb Type Library into the XE8 RAD) and the problem occurs in both the D6 and XE8 build.
The error occurs in the 'arrived' procedure, when the error occurs I haven't been able to access the 'Body' in any way.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem (or debug it further)?

[An old post that had a similar issue (I haven't been able to pin the problem on an issue with the XML payload).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192217/eoleexception-on-accessing-message-body)

**Error Log**

```
error, TMyThread.Arrived (VarIsStr Test): ClassName: EOleException, Error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation
error, TMyThread.Arrived (QueueMessage Assignment): ClassName: EOleException, Error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation,Label: adf7cea1-7be8-4382-8687-f4ea0f8a5e50, Body Length: 871, Msg Class: 0, Cursor: 0, Encrypt Algorithm: 26625, Journal: 1, Sender Version: 16
```

**Code**

```
procedure TMyThread.Arrived(ASender: TObject; const Queue: IDispatch; Cursor: Integer);
var
  strMSMQMessage, strMsg, strMessageFile, strMessageProperties: string;
  blnMsgAssigned: boolean;
  intBodyLength, intMessageClass: integer;
  wstrLabel: WideString;
  intEncryptAlgorithm, intJournal, intSenderVersion: longint;
  QueueMessage: IMSMQMessage3;
  varTransaction, varWantDestinationQueue, varWantBody, varReceiveTimeOut, varWantConnectorType: OLEVariant;

begin
  QueueMessage:= nil;
  strMSMQMessage:= '';
  intBodyLength:= 0;
  wstrLabel:= '';
  strMessageProperties:= '';
  blnMsgAssigned:= False;
  try
    varTransaction:= False;
    varWantDestinationQueue:= False;
    varWantBody:= True;
    varReceiveTimeOut:= 30000;
    varWantConnectorType:= False;
    QueueMessage:= IUnknown(Variant(FQueue).Receive(varTransaction, varWantDestinationQueue, varWantBody, varReceiveTimeOut, varWantConnectorType)) as IMSMQMessage3;
    if Assigned(QueueMessage) then
    begin
      intBodyLength:= QueueMessage.BodyLength;
      intMessageClass:= QueueMessage.MsgClass;
      wstrLabel:= QueueMessage.Label_;
      intEncryptAlgorithm:= QueueMessage.EncryptAlgorithm;
      intJournal:= QueueMessage.Journal;
      intSenderVersion:= QueueMessage.SenderVersion;
      strMessageProperties:= 'Label: '+wstrLabel+', Body Length: '+IntToStr(intBodyLength)+', Msg Class: '+IntToStr(intMessageClass)+', Cursor: '+IntToStr(Cursor);
      strMessageProperties:= strMessageProperties+', Encrypt Algorithm: '+IntToStr(intEncryptAlgorithm)+', Journal: '+IntToStr(intJournal);
      strMessageProperties:= strMessageProperties+', Sender Version: '+IntToStr(intSenderVersion);

      // Can trigger a 'Not enough storage...' error.
      // Body: OLEVariant
      try
        if not VarIsStr(QueueMessage.Body) then
          if Assigned(FEventLog) then
            FEventLog.AppendToFile('debug', 'TMyThread.Arrived: VarIsStr = False', TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
      except
        on E: Exception do
          if Assigned(FEventLog) then
          begin
            strMsg:= 'TMyThread.Arrived (VarIsStr Test): ClassName: '+E.ClassName+', Error: '+E.Message+strMsg;
            FEventLog.AppendToFile('error', strMsg, TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
          end;
      end;
      strMSMQMessage:= VarToStrDef(QueueMessage.Body, '');
      blnMsgAssigned:= True;
    end;
    QueueMessage:= nil;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      if Assigned(FEventLog) then
      begin
        strMsg:= 'TMyThread.Arrived (QueueMessage Assignment): ClassName: '+E.ClassName+', Error: '+E.Message+','+strMessageProperties;
        FEventLog.AppendToFile('error', strMsg, TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if blnMsgAssigned then
  begin
    strMessageFile:= TTMSMQService.FArchiveFilePath+'PA.'+FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd.hhmmsszzz', Now)+'.'+IntToStr(intBodyLength)+'.xml';
    if Assigned(FMessageLog) then
      FMessageLog.WriteToFile(strMessageFile, strMSMQMessage);

    // Debug.
    if Assigned(FEventLog) then
      FEventLog.AppendToFile('debug', 'TMyThread.Arrived: Message Properties: '+strMessageProperties, TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);

    if blnMsgAssigned and (Length(strMSMQMessage) > 0) then
      ParseIncomingMessage(strMSMQMessage);
  end else begin
    if Assigned(FEventLog) then
    begin
      strMsg:= 'TMyThread.Arrived: Error: QueueMessage not assigned';
      FEventLog.AppendToFile('error', strMsg, TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
    end;

  end;

  // Debug.
  if Assigned(FEventLog) then
    FEventLog.AppendToFile('debug', 'TMyThread.Arrived: Try EnableNotification', TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
  try
    FQueue.EnableNotification(FEvent.DefaultInterface, EmptyParam, FTimeOut);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      if Assigned(FEventLog) then
      begin
        strMsg:= 'TMyThread.Arrived (EnableNotification): ClassName: '+E.ClassName+', Error: '+E.Message;
        FEventLog.AppendToFile('error', strMsg, TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
      end;
    end;
  end;

end;


procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  strMsg: string;

begin
  inherited;
  FreeOnTerminate:= False;
  Randomize;
  try
    try
      FQueueInfo:= CreateCOMObject(CLASS_MSMQQueueInfo) as IMSMQQueueInfo3;
      FQueueInfo.FormatName:= FFormatNameOut;
      FTimeOut:= -1;
      FEvent:= TMSMQEvent.Create(nil);
      FEvent.OnArrived:= Arrived;
      FEvent.OnArrivedError:= ArrivedError;
      FConnected:= OpenListeningQueue;
      while not Terminated do
      begin
        if not FConnected then
        begin
          CloseListeningQueue;
          FConnected:= OpenListeningQueue;
        end;
        Sleep(Random(500) + 1000);
      end; // while not Terminated
      CloseListeningQueue;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        if Assigned(FEventLog) then
        begin
          strMsg:= 'TMyThread.Execute: ClassName: '+E.ClassName+', Error: '+E.Message;
          FEventLog.AppendToFile('error', strMsg, TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    if Assigned(FEvent) then
      FEvent.Free;
    FQueueInfo:= nil;
  end;
end;


  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FFormatNameOut: string;
    FEventLog: TEventLog;
    FQueueInfo: IMSMQQueueInfo3;
    FQueue: IMSMQQueue3;
    FEvent: TMSMQEvent;
    FTimeOut: OLEVariant;
    FConnected: boolean;
    FMessageLog: TMessageLog;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure ParseIncomingMessage(const strMessage: string);
    function OpenListeningQueue: boolean;
    procedure CloseListeningQueue;
  public
    procedure Arrived(ASender: TObject; const Queue: IDispatch; Cursor: Integer);
    procedure ArrivedError(ASender: TObject; const Queue: IDispatch; ErrorCode: Integer; Cursor: Integer);
    constructor Create(const FormatNameOut: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(const FormatNameOut: string);
const
  PA_EVENTFILE = 'msmqpatevents.txt';

begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  inherited Create(False);
  FConnected:= False;
  FFormatNameOut:= FormatNameOut;
  FEventLog:= TEventLog.Create(TTMSMQService.FLogFilePath+PA_EVENTFILE);
  FMessageLog:= TMessageLog.Create;
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FEventLog);
  FreeAndNil(FMessageLog);
  inherited Destroy;
  CoUninitialize;
end;

function TMyThread.OpenListeningQueue: boolean;
var
  strMsg: string;

begin

  // Debug.
  if Assigned(FEventLog) then
    FEventLog.AppendToFile('debug', 'TMyThread.OpenListeningQueue', TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
  Result:= False;
  try
    FQueue:= FQueueInfo.Open(MQ_RECEIVE_ACCESS, MQ_DENY_NONE);
    FQueue.EnableNotification(FEvent.DefaultInterface, EmptyParam, FTimeOut);
    Result:= (FQueue.IsOpen = 1);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      if Assigned(FEventLog) then
      begin
        strMsg:= 'TMyThread.OpenListeningQueue: ClassName: '+E.ClassName+', Error: '+E.Message;
        FEventLog.AppendToFile('error', strMsg, TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.CloseListeningQueue;
var
  strMsg: string;

begin

  // Debug.
  if Assigned(FEventLog) then
    FEventLog.AppendToFile('debug', 'TMyThread.CloseListeningQueue', TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
  try
    if Assigned(FQueue) then
      if FQueue.IsOpen = 1 then
        FQueue.Close;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      if Assigned(FEventLog) then
      begin
        strMsg:= 'TMyThread.CloseListeningQueue: ClassName: '+E.ClassName+', Error: '+E.Message;
        FEventLog.AppendToFile('error', strMsg, TTMSMQService.FServiceVersion, TTMSMQService.FDatabaseVersion);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please check the relevance of this known issue with regards to your application: http://stackoverflow.com/q/507853/224704

Comment: @CraigYoung, Thanks, I had already applied the ControlsAtomFix and OleCtrls patch to the D6 code (Don't think that the patches are required in XE8).
I haven't tried the heap tweak, I'll do this now.
The Service is deployed to a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, SharedSection is currently set to 1024,20480,768

Comment: There is not enough information about the EOleException. The text message "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" may mean severalerrors. What is the ErrorCode: HResult value? What are the HelpFile/Source string values? It may help indentifying the error cause.

Comment: BTW; your thread should call CoInitialize first place in its Execute method.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, Thanks, I call CoInitialize in the constructor (I've augmented the code block with some additional procedures noted in the edit), I'll log the other details and feedback